# Thunderbird flatpak install crash in a few seconds, after OS reboot (works before reboot) - Debian, KDE, Wayland

Tags: debian, kde, wayland, flatpak

I'm on Debian 12 KDE, Wayland(for monitor scaling).

I set a custom location for flatpak in `/etc/flatpak/installations.d/extra.conf`

```
[Installation "port"]
Path=/port/flatpak/
DisplayName=Extra Installation
StorageType=harddisk
```

and installed Thunderbird using:

```
flatpak --installation=port install flathub org.mozilla.Thunderbird
```

After install I can run Thunderbird, set account etc without any issues.

After reboot when I run Thunderbird from the application launcher(shortcut created by the OS), from CLI or Discover Thunderbird always crash after a few seconds with no message.

I tried to reinstall, update flatpak, reboot nothing works.
NO idea what is wrong and how to debug/fix.